# Mysql collation issue with information_schema.TABLES

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
 select distinct name from 
  (
    select TABLE_NAME as name from information_schema.TABLES 
         where TABLE_SCHEMA ='my_db_name' 
     union 
    select distinct db_table as name from status 
  )t 
  order by name
```

With mysql (Server version: 5.1.44) settings

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                               |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                 |
| character_sets_dir       | /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `db_table` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `rank` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `style_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `db_table` (`db_table`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=68 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Further I changed my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
#
#
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
#
```

I dropped the database and re-created it, now I am getting error **Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'** . Please advise me what I am doing wrong. I am getting same issue from php and mysql command line

This works:

```
  select distinct name from 
  (
    select TABLE_NAME collate utf8_unicode_ci as name from information_schema.TABLES 
         where TABLE_SCHEMA ='my_db_name' 
     union 
    select distinct db_table as name from status 
  )t 
  order by name
```

But I dont like the tweak ,my question is : is there proper fix for this .As you see mysql global settings is set to proper collation but information schema is still using utf8_general_ci or so ?

Comment: This problem might be due to you are doing union system generated tables (from information_schema which are myisam) and user generated tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the collation of information_schema, you will probably find utf8_general_ci NOT utf8_unicode_ci. I don't know why.

```
USE information_schema;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

The other option besides defining collation in the query is changing your database tables to use utf8_general_ci. (personally, I prefer specifying collation in the query)

Keep in mind, there is also a collation setting on each table that overrides settings you see with (SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';). If you switch to utf8_general_ci for everything, you will probably have to run an ALTER TABLE statement for each one. If you have many tables, you can also do a mysqldump, find and replace to change them all, and re-import.